# Is it possible to set a default data type for properties in an Elastic Search index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is is possible to declare an object property on an index, and specify a `type` for all properties without defining them individually (they are unknown at creation time).

```
{"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "tags": {
            "type: "object",
            // all properties are keywords, or text
            "properties": { "*": "keyword" }
        }
    }
}}
```

These "tags" are simple `key:value` string pairs, where the value can be blank.

The issue I have is ES guessing the data type.  Once it decides the property is a date, well, every record without a valid date raises an error.

I am currently using `"tags": { "type": "flattened" }`, which seems less than ideal. Though it is at least *searchable*, it doesn't seem possible to match records exactly, e.g. `tags.host=wrk1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic templates to achieve what you want, you can find official documentation for dynamic templates [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html). As an example you can have a dynamic mapping like this for your problem:

```
"dynamic_templates": [{
    "your_template": {
        "match_mapping_type": "*",
        "path_match": "tags.*",
        "mapping": {
        "index": true,
        "analyzer": "specify your analyzer",
        "type": "text",
        "store": false
        }
     }
}]
```

In this case each type you have a dynamic field elastic search automatically will map it based on this template.

Comment: So *that* is what they are for!  Strange syntax but it appears to have worked great.